# Makefile on windows 8.1

Tags: c++, makefile

friday I have upgraded windows from 8 to 8.1 and makefile for a c++ project is not working anymore. Windows opens a window claiming error 0xc0000142 and when this window is closed shell gives error 66. Makefile is fine for other operating systems(there are no errors in makefile).
Do someone face the same problem? Is it a windows 8.1 problem or is it a mine problem because something went wrong in the upgrade?

Thank you!
Nadir

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem. I do not think that it is your problem, because I too have a program that has stopped working since upgrading to Windows 8.1. So far, I have not found a resolution to the problem, but if I do, I will be sure to let you know.

Comment: @Nadir I am sorry I cannot provide any information about the problem. I am researching it now.